# printing from a file with a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently learning python and I have difficulties with a certain part of an exercise:

> use !curl to download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftLearning/intropython/master/world_temp_mean.csv as mean_temp.txt
> # [ ] The Weather: import world_mean_team.csv as mean_temp.txt
> Open the file in 'r' mode.
> Read the first line of text into a variable called: headings and `print()`.
> Convert headings to a list using `.split(',')` which splits on each comma, `print()` the list.
> # [ ] The Weather: open file, read/print first line, convert line to list (splitting on comma)
> use a while loop to read the remaining lines from the file
> Assign remaining lines to a `city_temp` variable.
> Convert the `city_temp` to a list using `.split(',')` for each `.readline()` in the loop.
> Print each city & the highest monthly average temperature.
> Close `mean_temps`.

> Tips & Hints:

> Use the print output of headings to determine the `city_temp` indexes to use.
> "month ave: highest high" for Beijing is 30.9 Celsius.
> Convert `city_temp` to lists with `.split(',')`.
> # [ ] The Weather: use while loop to print city and highest monthly average temp in Celsius

I did the first part right but the second part which is printing each city with temp is difficult and I don't know how to solve it.

My code so far is:

```
mean_temp = open('mean_temp.txt', 'r')
read_line = mean_temp.readline()
print(read_line)
heading = read_line.split(',')
print('Heading list: ',heading)
city_temp = ''
while read_line:
    print(read_line[:-1]) # writes the first line in the file
    read_line = mean_temp.readline() # goes to the next line
    city_temp += read_line  # adding the line to the variable
    city_temp1 = city_temp.split(',') # split the line every comma to a list

print(city_temp1)
```

and the output is:

```
city,country,month ave: highest high,month ave: lowest low

Heading list:  ['city', 'country', 'month ave: highest high', 'month ave: lowest low\n']
city,country,month ave: highest high,month ave: lowest low
Beijing,China,30.9,-8.4
Cairo,Egypt,34.7,1.2
London,UK,23.5,2.1
Nairobi,Kenya,26.3,10.5
New York City,USA,28.9,-2.8
Sydney,Australia,26.5,8.7
Tokyo,Japan,30.8,0.9
['Beijing', 'China', '30.9', '-8.4\nCairo', 'Egypt', '34.7', '1.2\nLondon', 'UK', '23.5', '2.1\nNairobi', 'Kenya', '26.3', '10.5\nNew York City', 'USA', '28.9', '-2.8\nSydney', 'Australia', '26.5', '8.7\nTokyo', 'Japan', '30.8', '0.9\n']
```

​

Comment: Please condese your post to a [mcve] with a question that describes your problem. You solved parts of your task already - no need to replicate that here - simply create a minimal example. Walls of code and/or descriptive text leads to downvotes - it drowns what you want to achive in text we need to dig through to get to your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop should split the line into a list, then index that list with the correct integer to pull the city and high temp information. For example:

```
mean_temp = open('mean_temp.txt', 'r')
read_line = mean_temp.readline()
heading = read_line.split(',')
print('Heading list: ',heading)
# prints "Heading list:  ['city', 'country', 'month ave: highest high', 'month ave: lowest low\n']", 
# which means index ZERO and index TWO is the correct values to pull from each list created from each line

# Move onto the next line, we want to start the while loop with the first city 
city_temp = mean_temp.readline() # goes to the next line

while city_temp:
    # print(read_line[:-1]) # don't write the whole line to the console, we want to print just the CITY and HIGH TEMP
    city_info = city_temp.split(',') # This is the list 
    print(city_info[0] + ': ' + city_info[2])
    city_temp = mean_temp.readline() # go to the next line at the end of the while loop

# make sure to close the file like the instructions said
mean_temp.close()
```

Output of the above code is:

```
Heading list:  ['city', 'country', 'month ave: highest high', 'month ave: lowest low\n']
Beijing: 30.9
Cairo: 34.7
London: 23.5
Nairobi: 26.3
New York City: 28.9
Sydney: 26.5
Tokyo: 30.8
```

Comment: @Itay123 please accept answer if it solved your problem. Thanks!